# Make display:flex responsive while retaining alignment

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello fellow stackers.

I have used `display:flex` on a `div` which sits in the middle of the `Y` and `X` `div`, as [you can see here](https://jsfiddle.net/wvavfa2g/2/). However I want to make it responsive, which it NEARLY is! When I resize the browser wide down to around 250 pixels the `div` and the text within the `div` just stops responding.

Now I understand that if I remove `display:flex` it will allow the text to continue responding. However, when I do so the alignment drops to the bottom of the `div`. The misalignment doesn't display when I remove `display:flex` though which leads me to believe that there is something in my code which relies on `display:flex` to retain the alignment. You can [view the website here](http://kadeem.london). Please find the code below, and the Jsfiddle in the link above. Much obliged.

```css
 #registry {
    background-color:#fff;

    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
}




.pane {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    min-height:50vh;
    padding:6rem 1.5em;
    position:relative;
    width:100%
}
.pane .pane-title, .pane .title-section {
    margin-bottom:2em;

}

.pane-title h2{
 font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 1.875em;
}

@media (max-width:222px){
.pane-title h2{   
    font-size:1.3em;
}
}

.pane .pane-content {
    max-width:68em;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto
}
.pane .pane-content::after {
    clear:both;
    display:table
}
.pane .pane-row {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:3em
}
.pane .pane-row::after {
    clear:both;
    display:table
}
.pane.flex {
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    flex:1;
        flex-direction: column  
    -ms-flex-line-pack:center;
    -webkit-justify-content:center;
    -ms-flex-pack:center;
    justify-content:center
}
.pane.flex .pane-content {
    -webkit-align-self:center;
    -ms-flex-item-align:center;
    align-self:center
}



 
#registry {
    background-image:url(http://kadeem.london/Content/Image/KL.png);background-color:#e94378;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
             -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size:cover;
    min-height:110vh
}
#registry .pane-content {
    max-width:48em;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:6em 2em
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    #registry .registry-description {
        float:left;
        display:block;
        margin-right:2.12766%;
            text-decoration: none;
        width:65.95745%;
        margin-left:17.02128%
    }
    #registry .registry-description:last-child {
        margin-right:0
    }
    #registry p {
        text-align:center
    }
}

.registry-description p a{
    text-decoration: none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    color: #000;
}

.registry-description p a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section id="registry" class="pane flex">
    <div class="pane-content">
        <div class="pane-title">
            
<h2>Get In Touch</h2>

<span class="underline"></span>

        </div>
        <div class="registry-description">
            <p>I hope your liking my website so far. If you would like to work with me you can <a href="tel:+447941661853">give me a call</a> or message me on the email below. Alternatively you can view more of my <a href="">articles</a>, <a href="">designs,</a> and <a href="">projects.</a>
            </p>
            <br>
            <button class="connn"><a>contact@kadeem.london</a>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You resize it 250 pixels tall or wide?

Comment: wide, I've also updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contact button (`contact@kadeem.london`) is what is stopping the content from resizing down any further.

However, having said that, you probably don't need to worry about supporting devices that narrow - all devices I'm aware of are at least 480px wide in portrait orientation.